# How to repeat the concatenation of strings per letter in a string of letters with no spaces or with dashes?

Tags: r

Below is a simplified albeit representative version of the dataframe I am working with.

```
df <- rbind( data.frame(masterConfig = rep("ABC", 5), subConfig = rep("xyz", 5)),
            data.frame(masterConfig = rep("BFG", 5), subConfig = rep("i-k", 5)) )
```

I am trying to generate a third column in the said dataframe that would look like this for the first five and last five rows, respectively:

"ABC x, ABC y, ABC z"

"BFG i, BFG j, BFG k"

I appreciate the help !

Comment: What should the third column look like for the rows that are not 1 or 6?

Comment: The same: this dataframe could have only had two unique rows really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write a function which checks `if` "-" is present in the `subConfig` column then it splits it and creates a range of letters between them or `else` just splits it on every character.

```
get_broken_letters <- function(x) {
   if (grepl("-", x)) {
     indx <- which(letters %in% strsplit(x, "-")[[1]])
     letters[indx[1]:indx[2]]
   }
   else {
     strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
   }
}
```

and then for each row we apply the function using `sapply` and `paste` them with `masterConfig` column

```
df$new_column <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) 
      paste(df$masterConfig[x],get_broken_letters(df$subConfig[x]), collapse = " "))

df
#   masterConfig subConfig        new_column
#1           ABC       xyz ABC x ABC y ABC z
#2           ABC       xyz ABC x ABC y ABC z
#3           ABC       xyz ABC x ABC y ABC z
#4           ABC       xyz ABC x ABC y ABC z
#5           ABC       xyz ABC x ABC y ABC z
#6           BFG       i-k BFG i BFG j BFG k
#7           BFG       i-k BFG i BFG j BFG k
#8           BFG       i-k BFG i BFG j BFG k
#9           BFG       i-k BFG i BFG j BFG k
#10          BFG       i-k BFG i BFG j BFG k
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(masterConfig = c(rep("ABC", 5), rep("BFG", 5)), 
       subConfig = c(rep("xyz", 5), rep("i-k", 5)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I forgot to include cases where the below            
"South Seas ABCD & 1,2, 7 / South Seas C" would have to be transformed to "South Seas A, South Seas B, South Seas C, South Seas D, South Seas 1, South Seas 2, South Seas 7 /South Seas C. How do you think that could be coded? Thank you again for your help

Comment: @KarimKardous that seems like a different problem which would require another function. I would suggest you to ask a new question including all possible scenarios it could have.